# What is the purpose of proto_path in the protoc command

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

My bash script has the following code generate invocation for "Protocol Buffers".

```
protoc --proto_path=src --java_out=src 
src/com/domain/project/persistentThing.proto
```

That was from 2012. Today the [online documentation for Java Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) says:

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR 
$SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

This makes it seem like `--proto_path` is superceded. What was the purpose of `--proto_path`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-I` and `--proto_path` are the same flag: `-I` is the shorthand version.

The purpose of the flag is to specify a directory in which to look for imported files, much like the C compiler's `-I` flag, Java's `CLASSPATH` environment variable, Python's `PYTHONPATH`, etc. You may specify multiple directories by passing multiple `-I` flags; they will be searched in order.